# Send enter key in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, sendkeys, enter

I want to make a macro in vb.net but the only problem is that I added a function to send the enter key anywhere in the code and I don't know how to execute it in the code.
the code to execute it is: `SendKeys.Send(RichTextBox1.Text)` i also tried it with sleep and then enter and stuff or with Ctrl+M but it didn't work I also tried splitting the code but nothing works please help me.

Comment: can you add your code you have tried till now

Comment: I did if you would look below in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code to

```
Private Sub SendKeyWithDelay(sleeptime As Integer, text As String)
    Dim out() As String
    out = text.Split(" ")
    For i = 0 To out.Length - 1 Thread.Sleep(sleeptime) 
        SendKeys.Send(out(i))
    Next 
End Sub
```

**works perfectly** for me now thanks for the help! I hope if someone looks at this with the same problem they will read this.

Answer (score 0):

To send enter key you need:

```
 SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

Here you have more info about:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.6

With delay:

```
Private Sub SendKeyWithDelay(millisecByNow As Integer, keyString As String)
    Try

        Dim t As Timer = New Timer With {
            .Interval = millisecByNow
        }
        AddHandler t.Tick, Sub(tmr As Object, e As EventArgs)

                               CType(tmr, Timer).Stop()
                               CType(tmr, Timer).Dispose()

                               SendKeys.Send(keyString)

                           End Sub

        t.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'log here
    End Try
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
 SendKeyWithDelay(500, "{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Why do you need this delay? And what is the difference if you are on VB? C# or VB this method is the same